# How to Bind MahApps Spin with Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

I´m trying to use a MahApps Spin control in a login wpf form.
But the caliburn binding did not work.

```
<Controls:ProgressRing IsActive="{Binding Busy}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Busy"/>
```

And my model has something like

```
bool _busy;
public bool Busy
{
    get
    {
        return _busy;
    }
    set
    {
        _busy = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => _busy);
    }
}

public void Login(string username, string password) 
{
    try
    {
        Busy = true;
    ...
```

But it not show the Spin control on the wpf form

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your notification, you are notifying on the field rather than the property.

Change

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => _busy);
```

to

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Busy);
```

Comment: If I try to change the username textbox for instance, it changes without problem

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks devdigital